# Clickonce offline installation management

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I'm publishing my `wpf` app with clickonce.

I select install options 'The application is available offline as well', so each install or update is saved in "User\MyUser\Appdata\Local\App\2.0"

After I publish over 10 times, my wpf clickonce app makes so many folders in "User\MyUser\Appdata\Local\App\2.0"

[image]

They occupied almost 1GB of storage, so I need to find a way to remove unused folders.

How can I remove the older version of clickonce app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Unused Folders in older clickonce versions unless you added a unused File. but if its space you want to save just delete the older versions of the software you made(delete the folder). it wont harm your newer version. but keep one or 2 just in case your new release is buggy.